# Can't change javascript files

Tags: javascript, cache

I've deleted a javascript file from my server, but it appears to still be there when making requests to the web server. I made a GET request with cUrl to the specific .js file to make sure there wasn't any browser caching getting in the way, and the server still responded by serving me the file contents, even though the file does not exist. There is NO caching plugin installed or activated in the WordPress site, and the domain is NOT going through a DNS caching service like CloudFlare.

I've been having this problem with multiple WordPress installations that do not use caching plugins and are on different servers from different hosting providers. Any ideas on what's causing this phenomenon? I'm stumped.

Comment: How were you attempting to delete the file? FTP? SSH? WordPress? If it's the 3rd you may have a permission issue that's not showing up. Can you tell us what file it is? Some files are dynamically generated by WordPress, though I doubt this is the case with yours.

Comment: The file was deleted by FTP, and disconnecting and reconnecting to the FTP server, or refreshing the directory, confirms for me that the file is actually gone. But I appreciate someone trying to help.

Comment: Is it possible the url for the file is getting rewritten to another location? I'm grasping at straws here but I'm baffled.